# What is so soft about soft symmetry breaking?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model

Explicit symmetry breaking terms are classified as "hard" and "soft". If the the explicit breaking is induced by a term whose dimension is less than four it is called "soft" breaking. Does soft breaking has anything to do with low breaking scale? I tried to follow [this answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8013/what-does-soft-in-soft-symmetry-breaking-mean) but couldn't follow the "low energy" interpretation. Moreover, I think the answer is particularly addressed for soft SUSY breaking.

In short, why "soft"?

Comment: I've tried to add some paragraphs to the old answer indicating why the explanation works for soft symmetry breaking in general, not just for SUSY breaking. The rules are the same and may be literally applied for other symmetries than SUSY. But a sociological fact is that the term "soft supersymmetry breaking" is more than 10 times more widespread than the simple "soft symmetry breaking". It's the case of SUSY where the "soft breaking" has a very sharp and useful meaning.

Comment: @LubošMotl While you're here Lubos... :) Are there any resources you can recommend (e.g. papers, books) that very explicitly and hopefully in a somewhat pedagogic manner go through computations of one loop amplitudes for the bosonic string? A lot of papers I've found use a lot of newly developed fancy machinery, and I was hoping to find a barer, more brute-force approach to it.

Comment: What about Chapter 7 of Volume I of Polchinski's String Theory textbook? Something wrong with it? ;-)